# Spring does not recognize png file

Tags: java, spring

i can visit all the static resources except .png file.

below is my xml file:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/css/**" location="/assets/css/">
</mvc:resources>

<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/images/**" location="/assets/images/">
</mvc:resources>

<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/js/**" location="/assets/js/">
</mvc:resources>

<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/fonts/**" location="/assets/fonts/">
</mvc:resources>
```

There are some images including .gif, .jpg, and .png under the assets/images folder.

I can visit all .gif and .jpg files but i can not visit any .png files.

When i check network, i find it shows gif type when visiting gif files, but it shows text/html type when i visit png files. I think that is why it shows 404 with png file.

How can i solve this problem?

Below is the response of visiting png:

```
HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report
message
description The requested resource is not available
```

response header for png is:

```
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:984
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
```

response header for jpeg is:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:141683
Content-Type:image/jpeg
```

Comment: Maybe there is some filter somewhere that blocks you from looking up png files.

Comment: @ Redlab it is a new project and i have not write any filters. So some spring default configuration blocks the png file?

Comment: can you post the html response the server return? you should see it by using google chorme developers tool in the network tab

Comment: @Angelo Immediata I post

Comment: Confirm file name and path, including capitalization please.  It's a 404, not a media type exception which one would expect if it was file type related.  I've used loads of pngs in spring, never had a problem before.  What version of spring mvc are you using?

Comment: I agree with @Taylor it seems to be a not found exception

Comment: @Taylor i find all the png files are not in "tmp0/wtpwebapps" folder, that's why:( Thanks

Comment: So this question is no longer valid? Can be closed/removed ?